# get n dimensional Fortran array from subroutine output into R?

Tags: r, fortran, gfortran

I have the following Fortran subroutine:

```
subroutine test(d, i, nMCd, DF, X)
    integer, intent(in)                                 :: d, i, nMCd
    double precision, intent(in), dimension(i,nMCd)     :: DF
    double precision, intent(out), dimension(i)         :: X

    X = DF(:,d)+DF(:,d)

end subroutine test
```

I am able to compile it for R load it and run it. But instead of getting an array I'm getting a single number.

```
system("R CMD SHLIB ./Fortran/mytest.f90")
dyn.load("./Fortran/mytest.so")

input <- data.frame(A=c(11,12), B=c(21, 22))
.Fortran("test", d = as.integer(1), i = nrow(input), nMCd = ncol(input), DF = unlist(input), X = as.numeric(1))
```

What am I doing wrong?!

My output looks like

```
$d
[1] 1

$i
[1] 2

$nMCd
NULL

$DF
A1 A2 B1 B2 
11 12 21 22 

$X
[1] 22
```

The R version of this is:

```
input[,1]+input[,1]
```

Comment: How does your output look like? The as.numeric() looks suspicious.

Comment: @VladimirF I added that to my quetions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't figured out what this was supposed to do because I don't program in FORTRAN (And you didn't say what you expected in a language that I do read) but this is an experiment that delivers the sum of the items in the first columns of the input object, which might make some sense when I look at the code with the inputs. It seems possible that sending `1` for `d` to extract from `DF(:,d)+ DF(:,d)` might mean you wanted the sums of first columns. Notice that I just supplied an empty 4 element vector to X and made its Fortran dimensions the same as DF:

Source in file:

```
subroutine test(d, i, nMCd, DF, X)
    integer, intent(in)                                 :: d, i, nMCd
    double precision, intent(in), dimension(i,nMCd)     :: DF
    double precision, intent(out), dimension(i,nMCd)    :: X(i)

    X = DF(:,d)+DF(:,d)

end subroutine test
```

R code:

```
input <- data.frame(A=c(11,12), B=c(21, 22))
.Fortran("test", d = as.integer(1), i = nrow(input), nMCd = ncol(input),
                      DF = unlist(input), X = numeric(4))
#--- result------
$d
[1] 1

$i
[1] 2

$nMCd
[1] 2

$DF
A1 A2 B1 B2 
11 12 21 22 

$X
[1] 22 24  0  0
```

Further experiment, still without any knowledge of Fortran, trying to add the items in the first row together:

```
  X = DF(d,:)+DF(d,:)
```

Produced:

```
 $X
 [1] 22 42  0  0
```

Comment: Thanks. I added the R version. Your solution works, I just had to change the `4` for `nrow(input)` Thanks!