# get rectangular Fortran array from subroutine output into R?

Tags: r, fortran

This is a follow up of [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31572566/get-n-dimensional-fortran-array-from-subroutine-output-into-r/31573669#31573669). The difference is that instead of a one dimensional array i want to get a 2 dimensional array.

I have the following Fortran subroutine:

```
subroutine test(d, i, nMCd, DF, X)
    integer, intent(in)                                 :: d, i, nMCd
    double precision, intent(in), dimension(i,nMCd)     :: DF
    double precision, intent(out), dimension(i,nMCd)    :: X

    X = DF + DF

end subroutine test
```

In R the code is simple:

```
input <- data.frame(A=c(11,12), B=c(21, 22))
input + input
```

and I get a 2 by 2 data frame

I am able to compile it for R load it and run it.

```
system("R CMD SHLIB ./Fortran/mytest.f90")
dyn.load("./Fortran/mytest.so")
X <- .Fortran("test", d = as.integer(1), i = nrow(input), nMCd = ncol(input), DF = unlist(input), X = numeric(nrow(input)*ncol(input)))$X
```

But I get a vector of length 4 instead of a 2x2 matrix or data frame. I tried `X = numeric(nrow(input), ncol(input))` but it does not work

The only solution I can think is running after I run the fortran function

```
matrix(X,nrow = nrow(input),ncol = ncol(input))
```

Thanks!

Comment: in R you can also coerce a vector to matrix by adding a dimension: `dim(X) <- c(2,2)`.

Comment: Or even with more generality: `dim(X) <- dim(input)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've reviewed the documentation for `.Fortran`, `.Call` and "Writing R extensions" and have not found any instances where a Fortran subroutine returns a matrix. Furthermore, there is no matrix type in the `?.Fortran` help page, so I think my comment(s) might be the best solution:

```
in R you can also coerce a vector to matrix by adding a dimension: dim(X) <- c(2,2).     

Or even with more generality: dim(X) <- dim(input)
```

Obviously I cannot claim this to be from high authority, since I've not done any Fortran programming before. If you were interested in writing code that interacts with R objects in place, you might want to consider studying the `data.table` package's code. Most such efforts use C or C++. You might also consider the Rcpp or inline package interfaces. The Fortran interface is mostly used to take advantage of the many numerical functions that have been bullet proofed.